# What is the time complexity of performing a UNION on 2 tables in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, nosql, union

If table A has N rows and table B has M rows, what is the time complexity to UNION them together into one single table?

Comment: Depends how you union.  One to one?  N == M ?  One to many ?

Comment: A UNION is combining all of the rows in the 2 tables to form 1 large table. Why does it matter if it is one to one or one to many?

Comment: Yep my mistake, mixed with join.